# Connect with EF Core Driver v2.2

Tags: linq, linqpad

I wanted to connect LinqPad with EF Core Driver v2.2. my project is .NetStandard and I have DB connection string in OnConfiguring override method in AnalyticsContext class which inherits from DbContext, I have relations with table using fluent api and I have applied seed data to insert to Database.

I am having this error message, you can see
[image: Here]

What could be the solution for this?

Comment: Can you take a look in %localappdata%\linqpad\logs and see if a relevant entry has been written to log.txt?

Comment: I have removed seed data, to insert to database, from OnModelCreating it is working and connected successfully.